# How to understand why an algorithm uses additive or multiplicative homomorphic

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lwe

If we take the example of LWE (Learning With Errors) how does one know if it's homomorphic by addition or multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Why question has a deep answer since it is deep research! The How question is a lot easier. To check that how an encryption scheme is homomorphic look at the general [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism);

Let $f:A\to B$ be a map that preserve the structures.
$$f(x \cdot y) = F(x)\cdot f(y)$$ then we say $f$ is homomorphism ( in a very simple terms).

This is a bit different in FHE settings since schemes are semantically secure ( most of them) so the comparison cannot be made on the range ( encrypted message space) so you need to decrypt to see that.

To check the addition ( or any operation that FHE ( or partial FHE) uses) take two different inputs $x_1 \neq x_2$ and apply the rule where $\mathcal{E}$ stands for FHE encryption and $\mathcal{D}$ stands for FHE decryption.

$$\mathcal{E}(x_1 + x_2) = \mathcal{E}x_2) \boxplus \mathcal{E}(x_1),$$ we cannot check this, so we need decryption.

$$x_1 + x_2 = \mathcal{D}\left(\mathcal{E}(x_2) \boxplus \mathcal{E}(x_2)\right)$$

As done for addition this can be done for any operation. Why $\boxplus$ instead of $+$, the operation on the encrypted messages doesn't need to be an addition for addition.

So the general rule, let $\oplus$ be the operation that you want to test its homomorphism. Then

$$x \oplus y = \mathcal{D}\left(\mathcal{E}(x) \boxplus \mathcal{E}(y)\right)$$ where $\boxplus$ can be equal to $\oplus$  or not.

For example in [Goldwasser–Micali cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldwasser%E2%80%93Micali_cryptosystem)

\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}(b_1)\cdot \mathcal{E}(b_2) &= x^{b_1} r_1^2 x^{b_2} r_2^2 \;\bmod\; n \\[6pt]
&= x^{b_1+b_2} (r_1r_2)^2 \;\bmod\; n \\[6pt]
&= \mathcal{E}(b_1 \oplus b_2).
\end{align}

the multiplication of the ciphertext is equal to the X-OR of the plaintext this is mostly used in fingerprint validation on encrypted data.

[In the Paillier cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem)

\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}(m_1) \cdot \mathcal{E}(m_2) &= (g^{m_1} r_1^n)(g^{m_2} r_2^n) \;\bmod\; n^2 \\[6pt]
&= g^{m_1 + m_2} (r_1r_2)^n \;\bmod\; n^2 \\[6pt]
&= \mathcal{E}(m_1 + m_2).
\end{align}

As we can see the multiplication of the ciphertext is equal to addition of the plaintext. This is used for the aggregation of the data, especially in databases.

The ( textbook) RSA cryptosystem  on the other hand

\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}(m_1) \cdot \mathcal{E}(m_2) &= m_1^e m_2^e \;\bmod\; n \\[6pt]
&= (m_1 m_2)^e \;\bmod\; n \\[6pt]
&= \mathcal{E}(m_1 \cdot m_2)
\end{align}

uses the same operation on both plaintexts and ciphertexts.

Comment: The LWE case a bit harder to write. If there is an easy way let me know.